# Running ADC triggered by TIMER1_COMPB

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, adc

I'm trying to run ADC on channel 0 triggered by TIMER1_COMPB.
Everything seem to work ok but basic arithmetics is not working and variables inside ISR and even main loop don't get updated (x == 2 all the time)

Can somebody explain me why is it so? Even volatile variable was not changing...
Arduino UNO, 
IDE v 1.8.6

```
#define SAMPLES_SIZE  205

const int adc_channel = 0;
const uint16_t t1_load = 0;

// 250 corresponds to 8kHz
const uint16_t t1_comp = 25000; 

uint16_t samples[SAMPLES_SIZE];
volatile uint8_t samplePos = 0;

static int x = 0;

void initADC() {
  // Init ADC free-run mode; f = ( 16MHz/prescaler ) / 13 cycles/conversion 
  ADMUX  = adc_channel; // Channel sel, right-adj, use AREF pin
  ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)  | // ADC enable
           _BV(ADSC)  | // ADC start
           _BV(ADATE) | // Auto trigger
           _BV(ADIE)  | // Interrupt enable
           _BV(ADPS2) | _BV(ADPS1) | _BV(ADPS0); // 128:1 / 13 = 9615 Hz
  ADCSRB = _BV(ADTS2) | _BV(ADTS0);              // Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
  DIDR0  = _BV(adc_channel); // Turn off digital input for ADC pin      
}

void initTimer() {
  // Reset Timer1 Control Reg A
  TCCR1A = 0;

// Set CTC mode
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << WGM13);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);

// Set prescaler to 8
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS12);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11);
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS10);

// Reset Timer 1 and set compare value
  TCNT1 = t1_load;
  OCR1B = t1_comp;

// Enable Timer 1 compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1B);
}

void setup() {  
  cli();
  initADC();
  initTimer(); 
  sei();

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  while(ADCSRA & _BV(ADIE)); // Wait for audio sampling to finish
  cli();
  x = x + 2;
  Serial.print(samples[0]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(x);
//  for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES_SIZE; i++) {
//    Serial.println(samples);
//  }
//  samplePos = 0;

  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADIE);       // Resume sampling interrupt
  sei();
}

ISR(ADC_vect) { 
  int16_t sample = ADC;

  samples[0] = sample;
//  samplePos++;
  ADCSRA &= ~_BV(ADIE); // Buffer full, interrupt off

  if(samplePos >= SAMPLES_SIZE) {
    ADCSRA &= ~_BV(ADIE); // Buffer full, interrupt off
  }
}

//ISR(TIMER1_COMPB_vect) {
//}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the manual ADC conversion during initialization is `_BV(ADSC)  | // ADC start` should be there. Also `samples` should be `volatile`. I won't comment on the rest of the code, as it seems to be a work in progress.

Answer (score 2):

Timer1 CTC mode requires you to put the CTC `TOP` value in `OCR1A` (see Table 15.5 in 328P datasheet). You didn't, so the timer is running all the way from 0 to 0xFFFF.

Timer1 ADC trigger mode requires you to put the ADC trigger value in `OCR1B`, which you did, so every time that the timer passes by your trigger value (`t1_comp`), it triggers an ADC conversion.

In short, you need to set both `OCR1A` and `OCR1B` to `t1_comp`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, it's strange since I enabled CTC mode, but it started to work normally as soon as I reset Timer 1:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPB_vect) {
  TCNT1 = 0;  
}
```